# Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) Can't Find Solution

Tags: android, file, trace

I can't get my app to work! It has no compilation errors, installs perfectly. But when I click a custom button the application stops. I copied the whole java and xml files and made a simple activity, with one TextView, and it worked. It enters the activity and shows the TextView. Here is the java, xml and the logcat code:

```
package l.pocketformulas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Formulas extends Activity {

Button bAlgebra, bTrigonometry, bCalculus, bGeometry;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // FULL SCREEN & HIDE APP TITLE
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.formulas);

    initVars();

    bAlgebra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent algebraInt = new Intent("android.intent.action.ALGEBRA");
            startActivity(algebraInt);
        }
    });
    bTrigonometry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent trigonometryInt = new Intent(
                    "android.intent.action.TRIGONOMETRY");
            startActivity(trigonometryInt);
        }
    });
    bGeometry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent geometryInt = new Intent(
                    "android.intent.action.GEOMETRY");
            startActivity(geometryInt);
        }
    });
    bCalculus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent calculusInt = new Intent(
                    "android.intent.action.CALCULUS");
            startActivity(calculusInt);
        }
    });

}

private void initVars() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bAlgebra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAlgebra);
    bTrigonometry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTrigonometry);
    bCalculus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCalculus);
    bGeometry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGeometry);
}
}
```

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgr"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include layout="@layout/selectimg"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAlgebra"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="@drawable/algebra" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGeometry"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="@drawable/geometry" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/algebra"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/geometry"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bTrigonometry"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="@drawable/trigonometry" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bCalculus"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="@drawable/calculus" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/trigonometry"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/calculus"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the Logcat:

```
06-05 00:17:25.090: E/Trace(24203): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-05 00:17:25.450: I/Adreno200-EGL(24203): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.081_msm7627a_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL2820657_release_AU (CL2820657)
 06-05 00:17:25.450: I/Adreno200-EGL(24203): Build Date: 01/22/13 Tue
 06-05 00:17:25.450: I/Adreno200-EGL(24203): Local Branch: 
 06-05 00:17:25.450: I/Adreno200-EGL(24203): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
 06-05 00:17:25.450: I/Adreno200-EGL(24203): Local Patches: NONE
 06-05 00:17:25.450: I/Adreno200-EGL(24203): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.081 +  NOTHING
 06-05 00:17:25.940: E/copybit(24203): Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
 06-05 00:17:25.940: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(24203): <updater_create_surface_state:342>: updater_create_surface_state failed to open copybit, error: -13
 06-05 00:17:25.960: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x53fbc000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:61
 06-05 00:17:25.960: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40117000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:63
 06-05 00:17:26.300: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x544dc000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:66
 06-05 00:17:26.300: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4011d000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:68
 06-05 00:17:28.660: E/copybit(24203): Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
 06-05 00:17:28.660: W/Adreno200-EGLSUB(24203): <updater_create_surface_state:342>: updater_create_surface_state failed to open copybit, error: -13
 06-05 00:17:28.670: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54753000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:71
 06-05 00:17:28.670: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x404c5000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:73
 06-05 00:17:28.790: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54de1000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:75
 06-05 00:17:28.790: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4089a000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:77
 06-05 00:17:28.820: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x53fbc000 size:1536000
 06-05 00:17:28.820: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x40117000 size:4096
 06-05 00:17:28.820: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x544dc000 size:1536000
 06-05 00:17:28.820: D/memalloc(24203): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4011d000 size:4096
```

Comment: Forget to mention that I try it on my phone HTC Desire X, it's 100% stock.

Comment: Okay I got it... I didn't have width attribute on the buttons -_-

Comment: i have same problem with HTC Desire X, also stock  but no other devices (Samsung captivate i897 and HTC Sebsation 4G), but i have set width to views.

Comment: What you have posted is not the "real" error log, but rather a secondary one which seems to result from an error in the factory packaged error handler which was triggered by the error in your app.  Having to dig back to find the "real" error (if any) amidst noisy factory code bugs is an unfortunately frequent problem on Android.